# SugarCRM: How to remove account & contact relationship through hook logic

Tags: sugarcrm

I have the following code to remove the relationship between an account and contact but its not working:

```
$bean->accounts->delete("account id here");
```

Does anyone have a working example of removing the account & contact relationship through a logic hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
$contact->load_relationship("accounts");
$contact->accounts->delete($contact->id, $account->id);
```

See /data/Link2.php for more available functions.

Comment: thanks. I was able to figure it out, the issue I was having was using $bean->save()  in an after save logic hook, for some reason saving it would cancel out the changes I made